# Why does this function get wrong argument from iterator?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a Space Invaders clone for IT project on uni. All the methods work, but I have a problem with deleting enemies.

I redone my code to use iterators. I store enemies in vector(horizontal) of vectors(vertical) of Enemy. The code works fine until i shoot more than 2 projectiles at a time when it gives me an error.

```cpp
if (projectiles.size() != 0)
        {
            for (auto itr_columns = enemies.begin(); itr_columns != enemies.end(); itr_columns++)
            {
                for (auto itr_rows = itr_columns->begin(); itr_rows != itr_columns->end();)
                {
                    if (projectiles.size() == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    for (auto itr_projectiles = projectiles.begin(); itr_projectiles != projectiles.end();)
                    {
                        if (itr_projectiles->Collision(*itr_rows))
                        {
                            itr_projectiles = projectiles.erase(itr_projectiles);
                            itr_rows = itr_columns->erase(itr_rows);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            itr_rows++;
                            itr_projectiles++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

That's the error i get:
line: if (itr_projectiles->Collision(*itr_rows))

Expression: can't dereference out of range vector iterator

Comment: itr_rows++; nested in the other loop seem fishy... BTW, one could find it hard to debug code that we can't run... did you try to use a debugger of analyser like valgrind? did you try to write down your algo before trying to implement it?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using built-in debugger in Visual Studio.itr_columns goes through enemy columns, and itr_rows goes through rows of one column. I wrote the algo on paper and it should work. On PC it works, but up to projectiles.size()=2, on 3 it just crashes with the error i Wrote earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the instruction :

```
itr_rows = itr_columns->erase(itr_rows);
```

By doing that, you invalidate the iterators of **itr_columns** while you're are in the loop, which does use these iterators.

Never call functions invalidating iterators when you a are in a loop.